# Google diffchart with google sheets as a source?

Tags: google-visualization

This is a rather basic question about whether or not it is possible to create a diffchart (scatter in particular) not from data in the code but from data in a google sheet.
I can create a diffchart with inline data following https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/diffchart. Substituting the hardcoded data with calls to a google sheet the 'before' and 'after' graphs are drawn without a problem but the diffchart does not draw.
Does the "computeDiff(oldData, newData)" method work with google sheets?

PS: What I want to achieve is a directional vector from a point with the point representing wave height on the scatter graph and the vector representing the direction based on dynamically changing data from a google sheet (ie the olddata is just the date and height and the newdata is a tirgonometrically recalculated date and height based on direction).